# Why Quartz.net is shutting down despite RepeatForever()

Tags: asp.net-core, cron, quartz.net

I'm using Quartz.Net in my asp.net Core web application to trigger a job every 5 minutes. But it stops with no reason after a while... Could you have a look at my configuration or/and to the Quartz'logs ?

This is my configuration in program.cs

```
services.AddQuartz(q =>
{
q.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionScopedJobFactory();

var jobKey = new JobKey("AppPushJob");

q.AddJob<AppPushJob>(opts => opts.WithIdentity(jobKey));

// Create a trigger for the job
q.AddTrigger(opts => opts
    .ForJob(jobKey) // link to the AppPushJob
    .WithIdentity("AppPushJob-trigger") // give the trigger a unique name
    .WithCronSchedule("0 0/5 6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23 * * ?")); ; // run every 5 minutes de 6h à 23h, tous les jours  
    });
            
// Add the Quartz.NET hosted service
services.AddQuartzHostedService(
            q => q.WaitForJobsToComplete = true
);
```

The job start and do whatever it is supposed to do. It repeats the process a few times and then shuts down.

This is the log for START event :

```
2021-02-04 14:05:28.026 +01:00 Information   Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: Quartz.Core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
2021-02-04 14:05:28.026 +01:00 Information   Quartz Scheduler v."3.2.3.0" created.
2021-02-04 14:05:28.027 +01:00 Information   JobFactory set to: Quartz.Simpl.MicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory
2021-02-04 14:05:28.027 +01:00 Information   RAMJobStore initialized.
2021-02-04 14:05:28.032 +01:00 Information   Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v3.2.3.0)     'QuartzScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'Quartz.Simpl.DefaultThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'Quartz.Simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.
```

This is the log for END event :

```
2021-02-04 14:25:30.767 +01:00 Debug   Trigger instruction : NoInstruction
2021-02-04 14:25:51.659 +01:00 Debug   Batch acquisition of 0 triggers
2021-02-04 14:26:14.861 +01:00 Debug   Batch acquisition of 0 triggers
2021-02-04 14:26:26.741 +01:00 Information   Scheduler "QuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED" shutting down.
2021-02-04 14:26:26.744 +01:00 Information   Scheduler QuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED paused.
2021-02-04 14:26:26.752 +01:00 Debug   Shutting down threadpool...
2021-02-04 14:26:26.752 +01:00 Debug   Waiting for 0 threads to complete.
2021-02-04 14:26:26.752 +01:00 Debug   No executing jobs remaining, all threads stopped.
2021-02-04 14:26:26.752 +01:00 Debug   Shutdown of threadpool complete.
2021-02-04 14:26:26.758 +01:00 Information   Scheduler QuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED Shutdown complete.
```

I thought the cron configuration was wrong but event with this config, I get the same behavior.

```
q.AddTrigger(opts => opts
    .ForJob(jobKey) // link to the AppPushJob
    .WithIdentity("AppPushJob-trigger") // give the trigger a unique name
    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
        .WithIntervalInMinutes(5)
        .RepeatForever())             //--> I thought this will be enough
);
```

Could you tell le what is wrong with this configuration please ?

The job is supposed to look for some specific data in database, and push them to android and ios application with ExpoSDK.

Thanks

Comment: Is your program exiting for some reason? Quartz will shut down as part of Program.cs exit. Does you main method have host.Run() / host.RunAsync() without exit conditions?

Comment: Thanks for your help. There is no reason in the code for Program.cs to exit. But I've noticed that it exits when there is nobody visiting the website anymore. Once I call the home url in my browser, the service is lauched again. How can I do to stimulate it even when there is nobody on the website ? I thought to set a while(true) in my main AppPushJob method, but in that case I don't get the purpose of the repeatForever()...

Comment: It's up to web server to determine if it wants to forcefully stop the site and thus also Quartz. You need to configure always on in order to prevent the site from going to sleep/recycle.

Comment: Nice solution, I haven't though looking on IIS... Next time ! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out the program.cs main method was exiting when the website had no visitor anymore.
I've looked for a way to force it to run continuously, but I didn't succeed (I haven't thought to look on IIS)... so I moved my program on our frontend application (rather then the backend) which has always at least one visitor.